# Format for setting Optimization flags in cBench

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization, intel-pin

I am new to Compiler related work. I want to analyse some source code before and after optimising with `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3` flags. I am using Intel's PIN tool for analysis purposes. I am using source code from cBench Benchmark suite. But I am not getting that how to set optimization option in that.
Tutorial of cBench mentions following statement.

> use __compile batch script with compiler name as the first parameter to compile the benchmark with a specific compiler, i.e. gcc, open64, pathscale or intel. In the second parameter you can specify optimization flags.

So I compile every source code with these three optimization flags as follows

```
./__compile gcc -O3
./__compile gcc -O2
./__compile gcc -O1
```

But when I analyse the object file in PIN tool, I am not able to find any difference in any of the 24 program set of cBench.
What is the point where I am missing.?